# Best practice for cross domain authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cordova, security

I have an existing web application, which I am porting to `PhoneGap`. I have replicated this successfully but I am wondering about the best practice for cross domain authentication. I should mention here that the existing authentication is using `System.Web.Security` and the web service that my PhoneGap application is communicating with is of the same nature.

Currently, I have setup the `Login` functionality, and it will post to my login method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Login(LoginModel viewModel)
{
    string error = "";
    if (!WebSecurity.IsAccountLockedOut(viewModel.UserName, 3, 60 * 60))
    {
        if (WebSecurity.Login(viewModel.UserName, viewModel.Password))
            return Json(new { success = true });
        error = "The user name or password provided is incorrect.";
    }
    else
        error = "Too many failed login attempts. Please try again later.";

    return Json(new { success = false, error });
}
```

This is being called from my `Javascript`

```
function login(data, automated) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://url/checkin/app/login",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        success: function(d) {
            if (d.success == true) {
                window.localStorage.setItem('UserName', data.UserName);
                window.localStorage.setItem('Password', data.Password);
                window.location = "index.html";
            } else {
                localStorage.clear();

                if (!automated) {
                    app.showError(d.error);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            app.showError(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

I'd expect this to work normally and it does, returning `success: true` if the credentials are correct. Moving onto other interactions with the service, this is where I am becoming confused. I would **not expect** `Membership.GetUser()` to work:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckIn(int id)
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser();

    // Do stuff
}
```

***How is this working? More importantly is it safe? Should I approach this in a different manner?***

When I login to the desktop version of the site (the original), in my cookies I have an `.ASPXAUTH` value whilst the same is not true for my PhoneGap application. This is why I'm confused as to how it's working.

I have an `Attribute` on my controller that when removed, prevents the application from logging in. However, I'm not sure that this is the reason this cross-domain authentication is being allowed?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

    private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }

                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I would not expect Membership.GetUser() to work"_ - why not?

Comment: @CodeCaster I just wouldn't expect it to be able to authenticate a call from another network. I am naive in this area of security, so it's only an assumption.

Comment: It pretty much depends on how your controller and application authentication are set up and how your client application logs in. Whether this would work or not cannot be said from shown code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Specifically, what needs to be shown?

Comment: how your controller and application authentication are set up and how your client application logs in

Comment: @CodeCaster Does that help in anyway?

Comment: I don't see cross-domain authentication anywhere. Different, authenticated calls to the same domain isn't cross-domain authentication, the latter has more to do with different domains using a single authentication token (think OpenID). Your client application logs in using Basic authentication I guess? Then on every request to your service, the client will pass the credentials.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure how the client is passing the credentials though. It has no reference to them from what I can see. I've posted the ajax request too. It's posting to a different domain

Comment: [`WebSecurity.Login()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx): _"When a user is logged in, ASP.NET sets an authentication token in a cookie that lets ASP.NET know on subsequent requests that the user has been logged in"_. Test it by calling `CheckIn()` on a session that has not called `Login()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I see. Where is that authentication token though? It's not set on the `PhoneGap` side, from what I can see there are no cookies.

Comment: Test it by calling CheckIn() on a session that has not called Login().

Comment: @CodeCaster `CheckIn()` returned successfully.

Comment: @CodeCaster Actually I'm mistaken. So is this an acceptable approach?

Comment: And what was the result of `Membership.GetUser()`? Edit: if an unauthenticated request fails with "401 Unauthorized" or "403 Forbidden" then yes, it is a sensible approach.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks very much for your help. If you can form this into an answer then please do.